# Necesito primero una asignacion a una variable antes de que cargue el diseño de una chart

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy intentando cambiar valores de un chart en asp.net  y mi codigo es el siguiente

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FechaLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            HoraLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
            DateTime prueba = Convert.ToDateTime(FechaLabel.Text + " " + HoraLabel.Text);
            FechaHora.Text = prueba.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            prueba = prueba.AddMinutes(-9);
            HoraGrafica1.Text = prueba.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica2.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+1).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica3.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+2).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica4.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+3).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica5.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+4).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica6.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+5).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica7.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+6).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica8.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+7).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica9.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+8).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica10.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+9).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            FechaHora.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+9).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

            masunminuto.Enabled = true;
            diezminmas.Enabled = true;
            unahoramas.Enabled = true;
            menosunminuto.Enabled = true;
            diezminmenos.Enabled = true;
            unahoramenos.Enabled = true;
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Inicio Select Señal ECG1 
        public List<byte[]> selectAlarmas1(int numero)
        {
            try
            {
                cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = SEBASTIAN\\PRUEBA; Initial Catalog = FUCS; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = SA; Password = sebastian");
                cn.Open();
                Console.Write("conectado bien");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("no se conecto" + e);
            }
            byte[] Datos = null;
            List<byte[]> numeros = new List<byte[]>();
            try
            {
                if (numero == 1)
                {
                    String cama = TextBox1.Text;
                    DateTime prueba = Convert.ToDateTime(HoraGrafica1.Text);
                    String Hora = prueba.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                    String Hora2 =Convert.ToString(prueba.AddSeconds(+59).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
                    Label2.Text = Hora;
                    Label3.Text = Hora2;
                    Label4.Text = cama;
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ECG1 From dbo.Alarm where PatientiID="+Label4.Text+" AND OccurTime between '"+Label2.Text+"'  and  '"+Label3.Text+"';", cn);
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
                if (numero == 2)
                {
                    String cama = TextBox1.Text;
                    DateTime prueba = Convert.ToDateTime(HoraGrafica2.Text);
                    String Hora = prueba.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                    String Hora2 = Convert.ToString(prueba.AddSeconds(+59).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
                    Label2.Text = Hora;
                    Label3.Text = Hora2;
                    Label4.Text = cama;
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ECG1 From dbo.Alarm where PatientiID=" + Label4.Text + " AND OccurTime between '" + Label2.Text + "'  and  '" + Label3.Text + "';", cn);
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
                if (numero == 3)
                {
                    String cama = TextBox1.Text;
                    DateTime prueba = Convert.ToDateTime(HoraGrafica3.Text);
                    String Hora = prueba.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                    String Hora2 = Convert.ToString(prueba.AddSeconds(+59).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
                    Label2.Text = Hora;
                    Label3.Text = Hora2;
                    Label4.Text = cama;
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ECG1 From dbo.Alarm where PatientiID=" + Label4.Text + " AND OccurTime between '" + Label2.Text + "'  and  '" + Label3.Text + "';", cn);
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
                if (numero == 4)
                {
                    String cama = TextBox1.Text;
                    DateTime prueba = Convert.ToDateTime(HoraGrafica4.Text);
                    String Hora = prueba.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                    String Hora2 = Convert.ToString(prueba.AddSeconds(+59).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
                    Label2.Text = Hora;
                    Label3.Text = Hora2;
                    Label4.Text = cama;
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ECG1 From dbo.Alarm where PatientiID=" + Label4.Text + " AND OccurTime between '" + Label2.Text + "'  and  '" + Label3.Text + "';", cn);
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
                if (numero == 5)
                {
                    String cama = TextBox1.Text;
                    DateTime prueba = Convert.ToDateTime(HoraGrafica5.Text);
                    String Hora = prueba.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                    String Hora2 = Convert.ToString(prueba.AddSeconds(+59).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
                    Label2.Text = Hora;
                    Label3.Text = Hora2;
                    Label4.Text = cama;
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ECG1 From dbo.Alarm where PatientiID=" + Label4.Text + " AND OccurTime between '" + Label2.Text + "'  and  '" + Label3.Text + "';", cn);
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
                if (numero == 6)
                {
                    String cama = TextBox1.Text;
                    DateTime prueba = Convert.ToDateTime(HoraGrafica6.Text);
                    String Hora = prueba.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                    String Hora2 = Convert.ToString(prueba.AddSeconds(+59).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
                    Label2.Text = Hora;
                    Label3.Text = Hora2;
                    Label4.Text = cama;
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ECG1 From dbo.Alarm where PatientiID=" + Label4.Text + " AND OccurTime between '" + Label2.Text + "'  and  '" + Label3.Text + "';", cn);
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
                if (numero == 7)
                {
                    String cama = TextBox1.Text;
                    DateTime prueba = Convert.ToDateTime(HoraGrafica7.Text);
                    String Hora = prueba.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                    String Hora2 = Convert.ToString(prueba.AddSeconds(+59).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
                    Label2.Text = Hora;
                    Label3.Text = Hora2;
                    Label4.Text = cama;
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ECG1 From dbo.Alarm where PatientiID=" + Label4.Text + " AND OccurTime between '" + Label2.Text + "'  and  '" + Label3.Text + "';", cn);
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
                if (numero == 8)
                {
                    String cama = TextBox1.Text;
                    DateTime prueba = Convert.ToDateTime(HoraGrafica8.Text);
                    String Hora = prueba.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                    String Hora2 = Convert.ToString(prueba.AddSeconds(+59).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
                    Label2.Text = Hora;
                    Label3.Text = Hora2;
                    Label4.Text = cama;
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ECG1 From dbo.Alarm where PatientiID=" + Label4.Text + " AND OccurTime between '" + Label2.Text + "'  and  '" + Label3.Text + "';", cn);
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
                if (numero == 9)
                {
                    String cama = TextBox1.Text;
                    DateTime prueba = Convert.ToDateTime(HoraGrafica9.Text);
                    String Hora = prueba.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                    String Hora2 = Convert.ToString(prueba.AddSeconds(+59).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
                    Label2.Text = Hora;
                    Label3.Text = Hora2;
                    Label4.Text = cama;
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ECG1 From dbo.Alarm where PatientiID=" + Label4.Text + " AND OccurTime between '" + Label2.Text + "'  and  '" + Label3.Text + "';", cn);
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
                if (numero == 10)
                {
                    String cama = TextBox1.Text;
                    DateTime prueba = Convert.ToDateTime(HoraGrafica10.Text);
                    String Hora = prueba.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                    String Hora2 = Convert.ToString(prueba.AddSeconds(+59).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
                    Label2.Text = Hora;
                    Label3.Text = Hora2;
                    Label4.Text = cama;
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ECG1 From dbo.Alarm where PatientiID=" + Label4.Text + " AND OccurTime between '" + Label2.Text + "'  and  '" + Label3.Text + "';", cn);
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("No se puede Consultar bien " + e.ToString());
            }
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (!dr.IsDBNull(0))
                    {
                        Datos = (byte[])dr.GetValue(0);
                        numeros.Add(Datos);
                    }
                }
            }
            return numeros;
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Fin Select Señal ECG1 


        protected void Chart2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<byte[]> Datos11 = new List<byte[]>();
            //byte[] Datos = null;
            List<int> graficoY = new List<int>();
            Datos11 = selectAlarmas1(2);

            foreach (byte[] Datos in Datos11)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Datos.Length; i++)
                {
                    graficoY.Add(Datos[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            foreach (int i in graficoY)
            {
                Console.Write("Y" + i + " ");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < graficoY.Count; i++)
            {
                Chart2.Series["Senales1"].Points.AddY(graficoY[i]);
                Chart2.Series["Senales1"].Palette = ChartColorPalette.SeaGreen;
            }
           // Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
           // Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        }

        protected void Chart3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<byte[]> Datos11 = new List<byte[]>();
            //byte[] Datos = null;
            List<int> graficoY = new List<int>();
            Datos11 = selectAlarmas1(3);

            foreach (byte[] Datos in Datos11)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Datos.Length; i++)
                {
                    graficoY.Add(Datos[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            foreach (int i in graficoY)
            {
                Console.Write("Y" + i + " ");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < graficoY.Count; i++)
            {
                Chart3.Series["Senales2"].Points.AddY(graficoY[i]);
            }
            Chart3.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            Chart3.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        }

        protected void Chart4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<byte[]> Datos11 = new List<byte[]>();
            //byte[] Datos = null;
            List<int> graficoY = new List<int>();
            Datos11 = selectAlarmas1(4);

            foreach (byte[] Datos in Datos11)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Datos.Length; i++)
                {
                    graficoY.Add(Datos[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            foreach (int i in graficoY)
            {
                Console.Write("Y" + i + " ");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < graficoY.Count; i++)
            {
                Chart4.Series["Senales3"].Points.AddY(graficoY[i]);
            }
            Chart4.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            Chart4.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        }

        protected void Chart5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<byte[]> Datos11 = new List<byte[]>();
            //byte[] Datos = null;
            List<int> graficoY = new List<int>();
            Datos11 = selectAlarmas1(5);

            foreach (byte[] Datos in Datos11)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Datos.Length; i++)
                {
                    graficoY.Add(Datos[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            foreach (int i in graficoY)
            {
                Console.Write("Y" + i + " ");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < graficoY.Count; i++)
            {
                Chart5.Series["Senales4"].Points.AddY(graficoY[i]);
            }
            Chart5.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            Chart5.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        }

        protected void Chart6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<byte[]> Datos11 = new List<byte[]>();
            //byte[] Datos = null;
            List<int> graficoY = new List<int>();
            Datos11 = selectAlarmas1(6);

            foreach (byte[] Datos in Datos11)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Datos.Length; i++)
                {
                    graficoY.Add(Datos[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            foreach (int i in graficoY)
            {
                Console.Write("Y" + i + " ");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < graficoY.Count; i++)
            {
                Chart6.Series["Senales5"].Points.AddY(graficoY[i]);
            }
            Chart6.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            Chart6.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        }

        protected void Chart7_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<byte[]> Datos11 = new List<byte[]>();
            //byte[] Datos = null;
            List<int> graficoY = new List<int>();
            Datos11 = selectAlarmas1(7);

            foreach (byte[] Datos in Datos11)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Datos.Length; i++)
                {
                    graficoY.Add(Datos[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            foreach (int i in graficoY)
            {
                Console.Write("Y" + i + " ");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < graficoY.Count; i++)
            {
                Chart7.Series["Senales6"].Points.AddY(graficoY[i]);
            }
            Chart7.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            Chart7.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        }

        protected void Chart8_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<byte[]> Datos11 = new List<byte[]>();
            //byte[] Datos = null;
            List<int> graficoY = new List<int>();
            Datos11 = selectAlarmas1(8);

            foreach (byte[] Datos in Datos11)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Datos.Length; i++)
                {
                    graficoY.Add(Datos[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            foreach (int i in graficoY)
            {
                Console.Write("Y" + i + " ");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < graficoY.Count; i++)
            {
                Chart8.Series["Senales7"].Points.AddY(graficoY[i]);
            }
            Chart8.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            Chart8.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        }

        protected void Chart9_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<byte[]> Datos11 = new List<byte[]>();
            //byte[] Datos = null;
            List<int> graficoY = new List<int>();
            Datos11 = selectAlarmas1(9);

            foreach (byte[] Datos in Datos11)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Datos.Length; i++)
                {
                    graficoY.Add(Datos[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            foreach (int i in graficoY)
            {
                Console.Write("Y" + i + " ");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < graficoY.Count; i++)
            {
                Chart9.Series["Senales8"].Points.AddY(graficoY[i]);
            }
            Chart9.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            Chart9.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        }

        protected void Chart10_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<byte[]> Datos11 = new List<byte[]>();
            //byte[] Datos = null;
            List<int> graficoY = new List<int>();
            Datos11 = selectAlarmas1(10);

            foreach (byte[] Datos in Datos11)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Datos.Length; i++)
                {
                    graficoY.Add(Datos[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            foreach (int i in graficoY)
            {
                Console.Write("Y" + i + " ");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < graficoY.Count; i++)
            {
                Chart10.Series["Senales9"].Points.AddY(graficoY[i]);
            }
            Chart10.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            Chart10.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        }

        protected void Chart11_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<byte[]> Datos11 = new List<byte[]>();
            //byte[] Datos = null;
            List<int> graficoY = new List<int>();
            Datos11 = selectAlarmas1(id);

            foreach (byte[] Datos in Datos11)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Datos.Length; i++)
                {
                    graficoY.Add(Datos[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            foreach (int i in graficoY)
            {
                Console.Write("Y" + i + " ");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < graficoY.Count; i++)
            {
                Chart11.Series["Senales"].Points.AddY(graficoY[i]);
                // Chart1.Series["Senales"]
                //Chart11.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
                //Chart11.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            }
            Chart11.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            Chart11.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        }

        //un minuto mas
        protected void masunminuto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime prueba = Convert.ToDateTime(FechaHora.Text);
            prueba = prueba.AddMinutes(-8);
            FechaHora.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+9).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica1.Text=prueba.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica2.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+1).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica3.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+2).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica4.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+3).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica5.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+4).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica6.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+5).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica7.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+6).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica8.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+7).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica9.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+8).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            HoraGrafica10.Text = prueba.AddMinutes(+9).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

        }
```

yo estoy asignando el texto de un label para buscar en la base de datos pero siempre me toma el valor anterior al que tiene el label 
Parece como si cargara primero la parte del diseño antes de la asignacion 
Quisiera saber como hago para cargar bien el label

Comment: Me esta costando un poco entender tu codigo, ¿te importa si te pongo una respuesta con el codigo reconstruido y pruebas, y de ahi ya seguimos viendo si falla?

Comment: porque tantos controles Chart ? y en todos los evento Load duplicas el mismo codigo?

Comment: en el metodo selectAlarmas1() porque tantos if que relizan el mismo codigo? no puedes unirlos en una sola operacion. Deberias simplificar el codigo porque asi como lo veo duplica muchas veces la misma funcionalidad

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el primer paso para entender que esta sucediendo seria simplificar el codigo porque asi como lo veo duplica muchas veces la misma funcionalidad.

Por ejemplo si tomamos el metodo selectAlarmas1()

- Se podria quitar todos los `if` simplemente realizando una busqueda dinamica del control en base a su nombre. En este caso aplique linq sobre los controles del webform
- Debes usar siempre parametros en la query, no se concatena en el string
- Asigna los tipos de datos correctos, si el valor es una fecha el parametro debes ser DateTime y no un string

  ```
  public List<byte[]> selectAlarmas1(int numero)
  {
      List<byte[]> numeros = new List<byte[]>();

      try
      {
          string connstring = "Data Source = SEBASTIAN\\PRUEBA; Initial Catalog = FUCS; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = SA; Password = sebastian";
          SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
          cn.Open();

          int cama = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);

          TextBox HoraGrafica = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Name == string.Format("HoraGrafica{0}", numero));
          DateTime Hora = Convert.ToDateTime(HoraGrafica.Text); ;
          DateTime Hora2 = Hora.AddSeconds(+59);

          Label2.Text = Hora;
          Label3.Text = Hora2;
          Label4.Text = cama;


          string query = @"Select ECG1 From dbo.Alarm 
                              where PatientiID = @PatientiID 
                              AND OccurTime between @OccurTimeDesde and @OccurTimeHasta";
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientiID", cama);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OccurTimeDesde", Hora);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OccurTimeHasta", Hora2);
          SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

          while (dr.Read())
          {
              if (!dr.IsDBNull(0))
              {
                  byte[] Datos = (byte[])dr["ECG1"];
                  numeros.Add(Datos);
              }
          }

      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Console.Write(ex.Message);
      }

      return numeros;
  }
  ```

Algo que no entendi es porque los datos que obtienes son byte[], pero esto no lo cambie porque no conozco el modelo aunqeu la idea es recuperar por el nombre.

Siempre es bueno mejorar el codigo para hacer mas facil encontrar los problemas, un codigo con mucho duplicado es complicado